# Heroku Memory Limit PHP

Tags: php, heroku

[This article](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/php-concurrency) on Heroku states that 128MB should be enough for most PHP applications. I perceive this as a bold statement looking at [composer](https://github.com/composer/composer/blob/4ebb747e12f0aa56cb6e13eef48395798e0db5e1/bin/composer) which increases memory limit to 1.5GB when run.

Specifically, we run into problems when generating PDFs or handling large database exports. I guess I am missing out on some best practice here. How should we tackle memory-intensive tasks on Heroku?

One way to do achieve this would probably be to write a `.user.ini` to increase the memory limit. But I guess this is considered bad practice.

Comment: Composer runs on the command line interface so there's no real chance you have 10 concurrent users all running composer commands. Typically all tasks that need lots of memory can be written as command line tasks to be ran in an asynchronous queue or on a schedule to ensure that you don't get many concurrent memory intensive things running at the same time.

Comment: _"128MB should be enough for most PHP applications"_ - I would argue that "most PHP applications" are not generating PDFs or handling large database exports.

Comment: @SeanBright I think it is quite common to generate PDF files with PHP. Think of invoices, for example.

Comment: @Chrisissorry I have no evidence to support this, but my gut tells me that _"most PHP applications"_ are simple CRUD applications. Either way, this doesn't answer your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(disclosure - I work on the Heroku support team)

Heroku is a platform that handles a diverse range of applications - they need a balance between maximum efficiency (for apps leveraging a lot of concurrency) and enough headroom for common processing tasks. This meant that 128Mb was picked based on the experiences of the PHP team there. (see https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/php-concurrency#determining-a-suitable-memory-limit)

Your example about composer using 1.5GB is interesting, but it's worth bearing in mind that tasks like dependency resolution and running build steps (which Composer handles) have quite a different profile from serving web requests. If you are doing something intensive like processing PDFs, [ideally this should be handed off to a background process](https://12factor.net/admin-processes) to keep the request as light as possible. Any background queueing system will work for this, but here's one example https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/php-workers

That said, one size definitely does not fit all and it's totally possible to change from the defaults if necessary.

There are a number of options for doing this, most of which are described here: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/php-concurrency#tuning-concurrency-using-memory_limit

A `.user.ini` file is one option, however this can take effect on a per-directory basis which may cause some confusion when working with teams.

You can also configure this at either the PHP-FPM level using a custom config file with contents like so:

```
php_value[memory_limit] = 64M
```

For these settings to take effect, you need to use the -F option in your `Procfile` command so the config gets loaded:

```
web: vendor/bin/heroku-php-apache2 -F fpm_custom.conf
```

There are similar config options for Nginx and HHVM described in the referenced article.

Answer (score 0):

To add up on @xavriley's answer, in case you don't have a Procfile because you just run your deploys with `git push heroku master`, you'll need to create one in your **root directory**.

Create a file named 'Procfile' containing this:

```
web: vendor/bin/heroku-php-apache2 -F fpm_custom.conf
```

Where `fpm_custom.conf` file exists in the same path as the Procfile.
`fpm_custom.conf` file should contain the memory_size desired:

```
php_value[memory_limit] = 256M
```

Once you have created this files, commit, push, and run again `git push heroku master`, the deploy logs should show the new Procfile running.